# How can I insert String into PostgreSQL table with linebreaks, using liquibase?

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

I have csv file

| scenario_id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | '\nStarts 25.01.2021 \n\nin' |
| 456 | '\\nStarts 25.01.2021 \\n\\nin' |

And liquibase changeset:

```
<changeSet id="insert_consents" author="Alex" >
    <loadData tableName="consents"
              relativeToChangelogFile="false"
              separator=";"
              file="db/changelog/dictionaries/consents.csv"
              quotchar="'">
    </loadData>
</changeSet>
```

First line inserts in PostgreSQL without \ : 'nStarts 25.01.2021   n nin'. And it is same in java String.

Second line inserts in PostgreSQL properly: '\nStarts 25.01.2021   \n\nin', but in java String it is: '\\nStarts 25.01.2021   \\n\\nin'.

How can I insert String into PostgreSQL table '\nStarts 25.01.2021   \n\nin', using liquibase?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an update statement to the the changeset after the loadData to convert '\n' into newlines.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).